# Указание схемы по умолчанию в отладчиках pgAdmin III / Ems Sql Manager

Tags: postgresql, отладка

Есть 3 схемы: public, meta, data

Пытаюсь отладить в pgAdmin III и SQL Manager for PostgreSQL 5.7 большую функцию из схемы data, но отладчик не видит ни таблиц ни функций используемых в данной схеме.

Функция большая и использует смежные функции из схемы data, поэтому явно указывать префикс схемы при вызове или использовать raise notice трудоёмко.

Можно ли указать схему по умолчанию? Подозреваю, что отладчик работает с схемой public.